# Rails 3.2 + mailer + image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have:

```
/public/images/fb.png
```

In /config/environment/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://192.155.90.155:3000"
```

In my mailer view:

```
image_tag 'fb.png'
```

Body of the mail contains:

```
<img src="http://192.155.90.155:3000/assets/fb.png">
```

**But I would like to get:**

```
<img src="http://192.155.90.155:3000/images/fb.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset-pipeline is made to simplify assets management . If you are about to use this nice feature , you should consider to stick to the conventions of the asset-pipeline . [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) you can find the suggested assets organization , which recommends to place images into `assets/images` directories (which you can modify in your `application.rb` file ) and normally are `app/assets/images` , `lib/assets/immages` and `vendor/assets/immages` . Summary : place your image in one of the asset-pipeline managed directories.